# React Native - Combine 2 Navigation Type in single apps

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I trying to implement 2 type of Navigation in my apps, Tab Navigation and Stack Navigation.

**My Desire Output:**

[image]

But so far with my code, I only able to implement one of them.

```
const App = TabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#7567B1',
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '600',

    }
  }
});

const Go = StackNavigator({
  First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  Second: { screen: SecondActivity } },

});

export default rootNav;
```

What change should I make to my code to implement these 2 Navigation in my Apps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const rootNav = StackNavigator({
     app: {screen: App},
     go: {screen: Go},
});
```

Method above can achieve the desire result however it may cause some issue, such as when perform Navigation to Screen, there will pop out 2 Header on Top of the Screen.

Improvement for Code above:

```
const rootNav = StackNavigator({
         app: {screen: App},
         First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
         Second: { screen: SecondActivity },

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a root StackNavigator, which has one route to your TabNavigator and one to your other StackNavigator. Then you can navigate from the TabNavigator to your other StackNavigator.

```
const rootNav = StackNavigator({
     app: {screen: App},
     go: {screen: Go},
});
```

Comment: However the UI become little bit funny, It add in another Toolbar on top of the apps and when I navigate to SecondActivity Screen, there are 2 Toolbar on top with 2 Back Button.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: You want to hold the TabNavigator header oder you want the one from your StackNavigator?

Comment: Then think about setting header:null in navigationsOptions of the second StackNavigator

Comment: Tried and both header gone in that screen, I think i will try look for another approach to deal with this issue, thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/614 it seems similiar to your problem

Comment: it is exactly the problem i facing, thanks for the link.

Comment: Sir, I have found a solution to fix the problem. I try to improve the answer by edit your answer. @kolbma